# Transporting data to Amazon Workspaces

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-workspaces

I am managing a bunch of users using Amazon Workspaces, they have terabytes of data which they want to start playing around with on their workspace.

I am wondering what is the best way to do the data upload process? Can everything just be downloaded from Google Drive or Dropbox? Or should I use something like AWS Snowball, which is specifically for migration?

While something like AWS Snowball is probably the safest, best bet, I'm kind of hesitant to add another AWS product to the mix, which is why I might just have everything be uploaded and then downloaded from Google Drive / Dropbox. Then again, I am building an AWS environment that will be used long term, and long term using Google Drive / Dropbox won't be a solution.

Thoughts to architect this out (short term and long term)?

Answer (score 2):

Why would you be hesitant to include more AWS products in the mix? Generally speaking, if you aren't combining multiple AWS products to build your solutions then you aren't making very good use of AWS.

For the specific task at hand I would look into [AWS WorkDocs](https://aws.amazon.com/workdocs/), which is integrated very well with AWS Workspaces. If that doesn't suit your needs I would suggest placing the data files on [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use FileZilla Pro to upload your data to a AWS S3 bucket.
And use FileZilla Pro within the Workspaces instance to download the files.